# Should I prefer hash algorithms with longer outputs for storing passwords?

Tags: security, database-design, hash, sha256, sha512

I'm building a site where security is somewhat important (then again, when is it *not* important?) and I was looking for the best way to store my passwords. I know that MD5 has issues with collisions as well as SHA-1, so I was looking into storing my passwords via either SHA-256 or SHA-512.

Is it wiser to store a longer hash variant as opposed to a smaller one? (ie 512  vs 256) Does it take significantly more time to crack a SHA-512 encoded password versus a SHA-256 encoded password?

Also, I've read about using "salts" for the passwords. What is this and how does it work? Do I simply store the salt value in another database field? How do I use that as a part of the hash value calculation?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered in great detail on the IT Security Stack Exchange.

Comment: Go to the IT Security Stack Exchange and search on "password hashing".  That should take about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For password storage, you need more than a mere hash function; you need:

- an extremely slow hash function (so that brute force attacks are more difficult)
- and a salt: a publicly known value, stored along the hash, distinct for each hash password, and entering in the password hashing process. The salt prevents an attacker from efficiently attacking several passwords (e.g. using precomputed hash tables).

So you need [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

For the point of the hash output size: if that size is *n* bits, then *n* shall be such that an attacker cannot realistically compute the hash function *2<sup>n</sup>* times; 80 bits are quite enough for that. An output of 128 bits is thus already overkill. You still would not want to use MD5, because it is way too fast (100000 nested invocations of MD5 might be slow enough, though) and because some structural weaknesses have been found in MD5, which do not directly impact its security for hashing passwords, but are bad public relations nonetheless. Anyway, you should use bcrypt, not a homemade structure.

Comment: Why is `bcrypt` so much better than another strong hashing method like `sha512`? What advantages, other than mathematical ones, does it have over other functions?

Comment: It is better because it is more resistant to dictionary attack.  Read the answers on the IT Security Stack Exchange to understand the situation.  Please make an effort to spend more time doing basic research before asking questions that are already well-documented.

Comment: There are other options besides `bcrypt` such as the older and NIST-sanctioned `PBKDF2` and the newer `scrypt`.

Answer (score 0):

Collisions are not relevant in your scenario, so MD5's weaknesses are not relevant. However, the most important thing is to use a hash that takes a long time to compute. Read http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/ and http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html (even if you're not using Java the techniques are still valid).

I would stay away from MD5 in any case, since there are other hashes that perform just as well.

Comment: MD5 is a bit too weak in today's standards. There are pre-made rainbow tables you can put your hand on, and it is not hard enough to find a source for a given image in the hash function (due to an algorithm fault). I wouldn't use it for passwords, for other things I sure might, depends on the goal.

Comment: Yeah, everyone I've spoken to has recommended to stay far away from MD5 if possible. I use it for file contents checks, but otherwise I've always heard to use SHA-1 if possible or SHA-2 if the possibility exists for it.

Comment: @TCS "it is not hard enough to find a source for a given image in the hash function": you imply there is a preimage attack. Do you have a source to back this up?

Comment: MD5 is not fine: it is too fast.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers here are giving you dubious advice.  I recommend you to head over to the [IT Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com) and search on "password hashing".  You will find lots of advice, and much of it has been carefully vetted by folks on the security stack exchange.  Or, you could just listen to @Thomas Pornin, who knows what he is talking about.